# Replace hyphenated range expressions with all values which exist in the range

Tags: php, string, replace, range

I have string as following:

```
$str = "Q1-Q4,A3-A6,S9-S11";
```

I need to replace the hyphen-separated substrings with a comma-separated string containing all values that exist within the range.

Desired output is `Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4,A3,A4,A5,A6,S9,S10,S11`

```
Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4,A3,A4,A5,A6,S9,S10,S11
|---^^^---| |---^^^---| |---^^---|
   Q1-Q4       A3-A6      S9-S11
```

Comment: Use `explode()` to split it at the commas, loop over them and extract the first and last numbers, then loop to fill in the gaps.

Comment: Try something like explode("-",$str); See: https://secure.php.net/manual/de/function.explode.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should get you going. This separates the sequences, adds in extra items and returns all of this as an array you can conveniently use.

```
$str = "Q1-Q4,A3-A6,S9-S11";

$ranges = explode (',', $str);
$output = [];

foreach ($ranges as $range) {

    $items = explode ('-', $range );
    $arr = [];
    $fillin = [];

    $letter = preg_replace('/[^A-Z]/', '', $items[0]);
    $first  = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $items[0]);
    $last   = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', end($items));


    for($i = $first; $i-1 < $last; $i++) {
        $fillin[] = $letter . $i;
    }

    $output[]  = $fillin;

}

var_dump( $output );
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the kind of task that `preg_replace_callback()` is perfect for.

Match the range expressions, then create an array of values that fall within the range, implode that temporary attay with commas, and finally use that new string to replace the original range expression.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/2vgd9))

```
$str = "Q1-Q4,A3-A6,S9-S11";

echo preg_replace_callback(
         '/([A-Z]+)(\d+)-\1(\d+)/',
         fn($m) => implode(
             ',',
             array_map(
                 fn($i) => $m[1] . $i,
                 range($m[2], $m[3])
             )
         ),
         $str
     );
// Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4,A3,A4,A5,A6,S9,S10,S11
```